# AVAudioPlayer volume low with VoiceProcessingIO

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, core-audio, audiounit

When using `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` combined with `AVAudioPlayer` this leads to the audio playback volume being pretty low. When switching to `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO` the playback volume is again on a proper high level.

It is depending on the order 3 steps

- `A`. Configuring the VoiceProcessingIO Audio Unit
- `B`. Creating an audio player
- `C`. Playing the audio player

The volume differs heavily on the order of these 3 steps.

Here is an example repository (_don't wonder why its called audiokit, its a collection of issues I am having with different audio sdks, and thats a collection repository. But this specific branch does not use AudioKit)

https://github.com/mlostekk/AudioKitSampleRate/tree/issue/outputVolumeNoAudiokit (branch `outputVolumeNoAudiokit`)

In our app the regular case is represented by the  button `VP3`. First setting up our voice processing input callback, then at a later time we create audio players and play them back. But this scenario leads to very low output volume

The order is `A -> B -> C`

#### Sidenote

The button `VP1` (`B -> C -> A`) leads to extremely loud volume.

The button `VP2` (`B -> A -> C`) leads also to extremely loud volume

The button `NoVP1` uses also `A -> B -> C`, which is the normal case, but in fact here voice processing is disabled, but we need it.

**Does anybody have an explanation why this is behaving like it is. And how to solve the `VP3` scenario to have normal / not so low output volume**

#### Note 1

This seems to happen only on newer devices (*iphone7 and upward*) even though a volume difference is also audible on older devices. The newer once are way more drastic

#### Note 2

It does not matter if the mode is `.spokenAudio`, `.default` or `.measurement`. It seems to depend on the `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` only.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? are you trying to mix audio from audiounit and avaudioplayer? Have you considered using the mixer audio unit?

Comment: We well, kind of. I measure the gai. Of the avaudio session before and after activating it, the apply a gain to the playback buffers to compensate that ratio.

Comment: @MartinMlostek could you pls tell me 1. how did you measured gain of audio session? 2. how did you apply gain to playback buffers? Thank you for your answers